# Can't get 3 plots to overlay in pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get 3 plots to be on the same canvas but only one is displaying. Is this the right syntax?

```
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(freqs,modfreqp,color='black')
pylab.plot(freqs,modfreqp,color='black')
pylab.hold(True)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(freqs1,modfreqp1,color='blue')
pylab.plot(freqs1,modfreqp1,color='blue')
pylab.hold(True)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(freqs2,modfreqp2,color='red')
pylab.plot(freqs2,modfreqp2,color='red')
show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(freqs,modfreqp,color='black')
ax.plot(freqs1,modfreqp1,color='blue')
ax.plot(freqs2,modfreqp2,color='red')
show()
```

should do what you want.